# What is the meaning of .classname .classname in css?

Tags: html, css

```
        .question-list .options {
            min-width: 240px;
        }
```

Max width property will apply to both( **question-list .options** ) or not ?

Comment: No, It will be applied to .options class within .question-list  class, If you want to apply to both classes, use comma(,) to separate them ```.question-list, .options```

Answer (score 0):

**max-width** property will be applied to an element with class `.options` that is **inside** an element with class `.question-list`

```
<div class="question-list"><div class="options">this element has max-width</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**min-width** property will be applied to an element with class `.options` that is inside an element with class `.question-list`

```html
<div class="question-list"><div class="options">this element has been targeted</div></div>
```

In order to target both `.question-list` and `.options` you should put comma between them:

```css
.question-list, .options {
    min-width: 240px;
}
```